# how to ignore rewriting css file with .htaccess

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z]{0,2})/(.*)/(.*)$     index.php?lang=$1&ctrl=$2&method=$3 [L]
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z]{0,2})/(.*)$          index.php?lang=$1&ctrl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.*)$                     index.php?ctrl=$1&method=$2 [L]

RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}                 !ctrl
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/?$                        index.php?ctrl=$1 [L]
```

and I need it to ignore rewriting included css files.

Thank's for you answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{0,2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&ctrl=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{0,2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&ctrl=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ctrl
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK, it works if my url is etc. home. But if I change my url to etc home/example, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you still getting 500? Tell me full URL you entered in your browser.

Comment: If my url is http://localhost/mvc-1/install it works, but if I change my url to http://localhost/mvc-1/install/installation/ it doesn't works. My web page run but css file doesn't load if url is http://localhost/mvc-1/install/installation/

Comment: Is `.htaccess` located in `/mvc-1/` folder?

Comment: No, in folder install

Comment: ok for loading css just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Ah, forgot about the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this before your other lines I believe.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Here's a tiny bit more information on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879029/don%C2%B4t-understand-rewritecond-request-filename-f-and-d

Comment: Did you put it before the first RewriteRule in your example?